# Crash iPad Photo Picker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using the following function to activate either the device camera or the image picker depending on the result of a UIActionSheet.  if fromCamera=YES then it works on both iPhone and iPad.  if fromCamera=NO then it works on iPhone and the image picker appears.  But it crashes on the iPad with the following error: **UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is not available on this device.**  I already know that the iPad can't display the UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent statusBar, but how do I avoid this crash?

```
-(void)addPhotoFromCamera:(BOOL)fromCamera{

if(fromCamera){    
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
}
else{
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}


[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

}

Comment: Surely someone out there has used the UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary with iPad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the UIImagePicker is inheriting the translucent status bar from your Info.plist file or from the currently displayed view controller.

What happens if you make the app not have a translucent status bar?

Answer (score 4):

If you set the picker to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary on the iPad, then you must(!) present it in a popoverview, otherwise you get exceptions. I do it like this, to atleast control the size of the popover (the standard size is too small in my opinion):

```
-(void)openPhotoPicker
{
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.navigationBar.opaque = true;

    //put the image picker in its own container controller, to control its size
    UIViewController *containerController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    containerController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = rightPane.frame.size;
    [containerController.view addSubview:imagePicker.view];

    //then, put the container controller in the popover
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:containerController];

    //Actually, I would like to do the following, but iOS doesn't let me:
    //[rightPane addSubview:imagePicker.view];

    //So, put the popover over my rightPane. You might want to change the parameters to suit your needs.
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 10.0,0.0) 
                     inView:rightPane
    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft
                   animated:YES];

    //There seems to be some nasty bug because of the added layer (the container controller), so you need to call this now and each time the view rotates (see below)
    [imagePicker.view setFrame:containerController.view.frame];
}
```

I also have the following, to counter a rotation bug:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    if(imagePicker!=nil && rightPane.frame.size.width>0)
        [imagePicker.view setFrame:imagePicker.view.superview.frame];
}
```

It ain't perfect, but it is ok for my testing purposes at the moment. I consider writing my own Imagepicker, because I don't like being forced to use the popoverview... but well, that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, take a look at my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677058/uiimagepickercontroller-crash-in-ipad-ios5/7839969#7839969